# iterate over a Python tuple

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to create a Python scheduler where I am trying to schedule a meeting on a particular day.

Here is the code:

```
timetable = [[""] * 24 for slots in range(7)]

WEEKDAYS = ('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday',     
'Saturday', 'Sunday')

timetable[0][15] = "meeting with Jane"

for day in timetable:
  for i, event in enumerate(day):
    if event:
      print("%s at %02d:00 -- %s" % (WEEKDAYS[day], i, event))
```

However when I run the above code I get an error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\workspace\test\2D.py", line 18, in <module>
    print("%s at %02d:00 -- %s" % (WEEKDAYS[day], i, event))
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not list
```

I am trying to print the day when the meeting was scheduled for eg: Monday meeting with Jane or Saturday meeting with Jane.

How do i print the exact day as well?

Comment: Print the value of `day` before using it in `WEEKDAYS[day]`, and you will know the answer.

Comment: `day` is a `list` not an `integer` you expecting.

Comment: DYZ, i tried printing out the day but it wont say which day.

Comment: Arman, I know that from the error. But how do i print the day?

Comment: Can someone tell me how do i print the exact day as well?

Comment: Just because you take day in timetable doesn't make you select a weekday or its location. You are defining an empty timetable and then taking out the empty list of each day from it and giving it as an index to the tuple. How can you expect that to work, please read what each of your command does and start from easier way than trying to do hard operations at once.

Comment: Thanks iamnotgoogle, I have edited the code now, I have literally tried everything but I am not able to print out the day.  I am just looking for the code which would print out the day as well.

Comment: You are still doing the same mistake, you are supplying a list as an index to select the weekday. Please please check how for loop, lists and tuples work, and your problem will solve itself.

Comment: @skyrocker, are you wanting `(WEEKDAYS[timetable.index(day)]` ?

Comment: @downshift: It prints 7 lines of output with each line printing " Monday - Meeting with Jane" which i dont want.

Comment: @skyrocker, i can't reproduce that output, I'm only getting one line showing the event. Since you're getting 7 lines of output, maybe try modifying the second `for` loop

Comment: @downshift : Thanks for taking time to look into it. So i ran an enumerator on the outer loop and it worked.

Comment: Cool! glad you figured it out, cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, the problem is that in `WEEKDAYS[day]`, `day` is a list of 24 events; you want to use `enumerate()` again:

```
timetable = [[""] * 24 for slots in range(7)]

WEEKDAYS = ('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday',
'Saturday', 'Sunday')

timetable[0][15] = "meeting with Jane"

for j, day in enumerate(timetable):
    # day is a list of 24 entries
    for i, event in enumerate(day):
        if event:
            print("%s at %02d:00 -- %s" % (WEEKDAYS[j], i, event))
```

Comment: Tom, that would print the following, which i dont want.

    Monday 15 meeting with Jane
    Monday 15 meeting with Jane
    Monday 15 meeting with Jane
    Monday 15 meeting with Jane
    Monday 15 meeting with Jane
    Monday 15 meeting with Jane
    Monday 15 meeting with Jane